# Extract text from HTML tags without printing None

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Let's say I got an HTML tag below:

```
"""
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="alphabet" colspan="3">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sound"><audio controls=""><source src="./sound/5/A2-1-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><audio></audio></source></audio></td>
        <td class="en">apple</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sound"><audio controls=""><source src="./sound/5/A2-1-2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><audio></audio></source></audio></td>
        <td class="en">amend</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""
```

My ideal output:

```
[apple, amend]
```

However, there is always a None value in my output. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_tags, 'lxml')
tr_lists = soup.find_all("tr") 

def clean_data(src):
    return src.find(class_ = 'en')

list(map(clean_data, tr_lists))
```

My output:

```
[None, <td class="en">apple</td>, <td class="en">amend</td>]
```

(the reason why I didn't use **src.find(class_ = 'en').text** is that it will raise AttributeError)

Is there a way to get the ideal output by not using the code below?

```
target = soup.find_all(class_ = 'en')
output = [i.text for i in target]
print(output)
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: since the second method seems to be the most suitable one, is there any specific reason why you don't want to use it ?

Comment: You could use `soup.find_all("tr > td.en")`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `AttributeError` because, the first `<tr>` doesn't have any  inner element with class as `en` and so the function `clean_data()`  returns `None`. *See the list that you posted.*

So when you try to get the text from each item of the list, you get this Error!

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The problem with your second piece of code is that it **selects all the elements that has `en` as class names**.

```
target = soup.find_all(class_ = 'en')
```

Since the data that you need is present only inside `<td>` tags, select only those.

Here is how to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="alphabet" colspan="3">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sound"><audio controls=""><source src="./sound/5/A2-1-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><audio></audio></source></audio></td>
        <td class="en">apple</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sound"><audio controls=""><source src="./sound/5/A2-1-2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"><audio></audio></source></audio></td>
        <td class="en">amend</td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')
td = soup.findAll('td', class_='en')
for i in td:
    print(i.text.strip())
```

```
apple
amend
```